# Leaflet placing marker on clickable polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with multiple polygons that I can click and select.
I wanted to add something else: placing a marker wherever I want on those polygons.

As you can see, I have selected a polygon (blue outline) and I have placed a few markers on the water (because water is not a clickable polygon:

[image]

But I cannot place those markers on those polygons.

Here is the code to add polygon and make them clickable:

```
 <?php foreach ($leafletPolygons as $index => $leafletPolygon): ?>
                var polygon<?php echo $index; ?> = L.polygon(<?php echo json_encode($leafletPolygon); ?>, {
                    opacity: 0,
                    fillOpacity: 0,
                    fill: true
                }).addTo(polygonGroup);
                
                polygon<?php echo $index; ?>.on('click', function (e) {
                    var currentPolygon = this;
                    
                    if (selectedPolygon) {
                        selectedPolygon.setStyle({
                            opacity: 0,
                            fillOpacity: 0
                        });
                    }
                    
                    currentPolygon.setStyle({
                        opacity: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 0,
                        color: 'blue'
                    });
                    
                    
                    selectedPolygon = currentPolygon;
                });

                polygons.push(polygon<?php echo $index; ?>);
                
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the code to place markers:

```
                var markerOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.marker-option');
                
                var markerColor = null; // To store the selected marker color
                
                var markersInsidePolygons = L.layerGroup().addTo(map1);
                
                
                function selectMarkerColor(event) {
                    markerColor = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-color');
                }
                
                function placeMarker(e) {
                    if (!markerColor) return; // Check if a color is selected
                    
var customIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'my-custom-marker',
    html: '<i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="color: ' + markerColor + '; font-size: 34px;"></i>',
    iconSize: [32, 60]
});

var marker = L.marker(e.latlng).setIcon(customIcon).addTo(map1);
                    
                    
                    markerColor = null; // Reset marker color after placement
                }
                
                
                
                markerOptions.forEach(function(markerOption) {
                    markerOption.addEventListener('click', selectMarkerColor);
                });
                
                map1.on('click', placeMarker); // Enable marker placement on map click
```

The weird thing is that I can place as many markers outside of the clickable polygons, but if I place 2 markers no matter where (inside our outside clickable polygons), then I cannot place more inside clickable polygons. Sorry if that's not very clear it's the best I can explain right now